# what causes git apply error already exists in working directory

Tags: git

i am trying to apply a commit from one repository and apply it on other repository. to do so, i am using `git show` to generate the git patch\diff then pipe it to `git apply`. for some commits, the following error pops

```sh
$ git show <hash> | git -C ../other/repo apply
error: .foo.txt: already exists in working directory
```

1. what causes `git apply` to fail?
2. how can it be fixed?

Comment: It sounds like the patch assumes it will be creating a file named `.foo.txt`, but it sees that it already exists. Git isn't going to try to merge them, because that's not something the patch tells it how to do. You'll have to remove or rename the file, apply the patch, the figure out how to reconcile the previous `.foo.txt` with the new one.

Comment: @chepner: would you like to post your comment as an answer so i could accept it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`git apply` generally doesn't try to resolve conflicts. You appear to have a `.foo.txt` file that already exists, and the patch expects to *create* one, not modify an existing gone.

You can try the following:

1. Delete the file, if you only need the file the patch will create.
2. Rename the file, and after the patch is applied, manually resolve any differences between the "new" `.foo.txt` and your preexisting one. (This may require an additional commit if you make any changes.)